What does Artin mean by "real numbers are the *only* ones needed for the usual for the usual algebraic operations?"
In page 81 of the 2nd edition Michael Artin's Algebra, he introduces fields and presents $\mathbb{R}$ as a familiar example, but goes on to say that "the fact that they are the only ones needed for the usual algebraic operations can only be understood after some experience". What does that mean?
I am guessing he refers to some general idea of sufficiency in terms of "size" (or some abstract ordering of sets).
But I am stumped since $\mathbb{Q}$ is smaller in terms of natural injection, cardinality, measure, and all the ways I know there is to order sets. Moreover, it is a field with the usual algebraic operations. Shouldn't the statement then be about rationals instead, unless we are talking completeness? Even $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ works if one is liberal with "usual operations".

You are misreading the passage.  It says:
You will be familiar with the fact that the real numbers satisfy these axioms, but the fact
that they are the only ones needed for the usual algebraic operations can only be understood
after some experience.
"they" here refers to "the axioms"  not "the real numbers".  The author is saying that the basic properties of the basic field theoretic operations suffice to generate a rich arithmetic theory.
here is a .pdf copy of the text, by the way.
